# How can I map something to Shift+Alt+O in Vim?

Tags: vim, terminal, shortcuts

I want to create a mapping for Shift+Alt+O in `Vim`. It works good in GUI version (`gvim`), but in console `Vim` decides that I do command "insert a row above this line and insert insert mode" (Shft+O). My mapping looks like this:

```
map <S-A-o> :CommandT<Return>
```

How can I teach `Vim` to perform `:CommandT` on "Shift+Alt+O" (it's a `NetBeans` shortcut which I used for 4 years, so I'm really addicted to it).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your .vimrc:

```
set <a-s-o>=^]O
```

To enter `^]O` do `<c-v><a-s-o>`.